# result incorrect when running tensorflow-gpu on CPU

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

In my project, I have several models trained by keras on GPU(backend is tensorflow-gpu), and when I test on GPU the result is correct. But when I test on CPU(set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=) , the return of model.predict is all NAN. My environment is as follows:

```
cuda 8.0
keras 2.0.5
tensorflow-gpu 1.2.0
Titan X Pascal
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Please give us some code which we can run. I.e. a reduced minimal test case which has the same issue and can be run as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the reason. There are several weights of neurons be NAN in my trained models. And when calculating the output of such a NAN neuron，the result of GPU would be zero but the result of CPU would be NAN.

Answer (score 0):

When you save a model, it records the device on which it has been trained. The model is restored on this device by default. In your case, I suppose your net has been trained on GPU.

To remove this information you need to specify `clear_devices=True` when restoring the meta graph. You can then place the net where it suits you.

Comment: I save my models by using ModelCheckpoint() function in keras and restore by function load_weights() of keras.engine.training.Model when using tensorflow as backend. I have no idea about where can I set clear_devices=True? Do you have any idea? Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about keras. My advices were specific to tensorflow.

Comment: Thank you anyway, it seems we are on the right path.